Failed to Precompile IJulia
After running compile IJulia in repl get the following error:
I tried downgrading to previous versions, but that did nothing. I recently upgraded to the most recent version of jupyter notebook and that seems to be the issue?
random text for character counts
random text for character counts
random text for character counts
random text for character counts
random text for character counts
random text for character counts
Precompiling IJulia
  ✗ IJulia
  0 dependencies successfully precompiled in 1 seconds. 13 already precompiled.

ERROR: The following 1 direct dependency failed to precompile:

IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a]

Failed to precompile IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a] to "C:\\Users\\User\\.julia\\compiled\\v1.9\\IJulia\\jl_CAE.tmp".

Please submit a bug report with steps to reproduce this fault, and any error messages that follow (in their entirety). Thanks.
Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION at 0x7ff9570a1f30 -- get_item_for_reloc at C:/workdir/src\staticdata.c:1704 [inlined]
jl_read_reloclist at C:/workdir/src\staticdata.c:1795
in expression starting at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\IJulia\bHdNn\src\IJulia.jl:36
get_item_for_reloc at C:/workdir/src\staticdata.c:1704 [inlined]
jl_read_reloclist at C:/workdir/src\staticdata.c:1795
jl_restore_system_image_from_stream_ at C:/workdir/src\staticdata.c:2905
jl_restore_package_image_from_stream at C:/workdir/src\staticdata.c:3333
jl_restore_incremental_from_buf at C:/workdir/src\staticdata.c:3379 [inlined]
ijl_restore_package_image_from_file at C:/workdir/src\staticdata.c:3494
_include_from_serialized at .\loading.jl:1011
_require_search_from_serialized at .\loading.jl:1471
_require at .\loading.jl:1748
_require_prelocked at .\loading.jl:1625
macro expansion at .\loading.jl:1613 [inlined]
macro expansion at .\lock.jl:267 [inlined]
require at .\loading.jl:1576
jfptr_require_32536.clone_1 at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.9.0\lib\julia\sys.dll (unknown line)
jl_apply at C:/workdir/src\julia.h:1879 [inlined]
call_require at C:/workdir/src\toplevel.c:466 [inlined]
eval_import_path at C:/workdir/src\toplevel.c:503
jl_toplevel_eval_flex at C:/workdir/src\toplevel.c:731
jl_eval_module_expr at C:/workdir/src\toplevel.c:203 [inlined]
jl_toplevel_eval_flex at C:/workdir/src\toplevel.c:715
jl_toplevel_eval_flex at C:/workdir/src\toplevel.c:856
jl_toplevel_eval_flex at C:/workdir/src\toplevel.c:856
ijl_toplevel_eval at C:/workdir/src\toplevel.c:921 [inlined]
ijl_toplevel_eval_in at C:/workdir/src\toplevel.c:971
eval at .\boot.jl:370 [inlined]
include_string at .\loading.jl:1864
_include at .\loading.jl:1924
include at .\Base.jl:457 [inlined]
include_package_for_output at .\loading.jl:2010
jfptr_include_package_for_output_46733.clone_1 at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.9.0\lib\julia\sys.dll (unknown line)
jl_apply at C:/workdir/src\julia.h:1879 [inlined]
do_call at C:/workdir/src\interpreter.c:126
eval_value at C:/workdir/src\interpreter.c:226
eval_stmt_value at C:/workdir/src\interpreter.c:177 [inlined]
eval_body at C:/workdir/src\interpreter.c:624
jl_interpret_toplevel_thunk at C:/workdir/src\interpreter.c:762
jl_toplevel_eval_flex at C:/workdir/src\toplevel.c:912
jl_toplevel_eval_flex at C:/workdir/src\toplevel.c:856
ijl_toplevel_eval at C:/workdir/src\toplevel.c:921 [inlined]
ijl_toplevel_eval_in at C:/workdir/src\toplevel.c:971
eval at .\boot.jl:370 [inlined]
include_string at .\loading.jl:1864
include_string at .\loading.jl:1874 [inlined]
exec_options at .\client.jl:305
_start at .\client.jl:522
jfptr__start_34279.clone_1 at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.9.0\lib\julia\sys.dll (unknown line)
jl_apply at C:/workdir/src\julia.h:1879 [inlined]
true_main at C:/workdir/src\jlapi.c:573
jl_repl_entrypoint at C:/workdir/src\jlapi.c:717
mainCRTStartup at C:/workdir/cli\loader_exe.c:59
BaseThreadInitThunk at C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL (unknown line)
RtlUserThreadStart at C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll (unknown line)
Allocations: 2997 (Pool: 2984; Big: 13); GC: 0```


I solved the problem by upgrading to the latest version of Julia (was previously on Julia 1.9.0 and now on 1.10.4).
